# Distinct Fermat numbers are coprime without recursion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

For m>n
$$\ gcd(F_m,F_n)=gcd(F_m \cdot F_n -F_m,F_n)=gcd(F_m\cdot (F_n-1),F_n)$$

Since $$F_m \cdot (F_n-1) \ is\ even \ and \ F_n \ is \ odd \gcd(F_m,F_n)=1 $$
I am in introduction to number theory so I excuse possible wrong statements and thank you for your help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Basic_properties

Comment: Please do not repost your prior [dupe closed questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4835190/242).

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: Your argument, if it worked, could be used to show that every two odd numbers are relatively prime. That is obviously wrong.

Comment: @TonyK $F_n-1$ is not necessarily even.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, thank you, I realized my confusion 5 hours ago and already deleted my comments right away. I think you can delete yours as well.

Comment: Not really - the reasons they have no common factor is more complicated than this, and this approach can't be "fixed," as far as I can tell.

Comment: In particular, you use a rule which is just blatantly wrong - that an even and an odd number cannot have a common factor. There is no way to replace that step with anything useful.